# Package conflict eledmac manyfoot?

Tags: incompatibility, eledmac, manyfoot

I have a few files using different setups for their footnotes/critical apparatus. Now I am looking into the feasibility of glueing them together using `docmute`. So far it went surprisingly well, or at least it seems so on first look, but now I'm stuck at a point where I suspect a package conflict between `manyfoot` and `eledmac`. I am adding the fifth file to the project, which uses `eledmac`, and suddenly I see `paraá` at the beginning of every page. As that reminded me of the `para` and `para*` options in `manyfoot` I tried to make a MWE using both manyfoot and eledmac together, and although I don't get exactly the same result, it is rather similar: On the second (otherwise empty) page of the output I get two lines each of which reads only `para`. Is this a bug, or a known package conflict, or am I doing something wrong?

[image: output sample]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[ruled,para*]{manyfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{A}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: At least in your MWE, swapping the loading order `\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage[ruled,para*]{manyfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{A}` solves the problem.

Comment: That does seem to fix it in my real example, too.

Comment: Although the docs do not specifically mention a conflict, I believe there is a presumption that users of `*ledmac` would be using the built-in footnote facilities, not those of another package. I suppose this is an example of "caveat utens".

Comment: @jon I would have liked to avoid mixing the two. However I am dealing with contributions from different authors which I have to glue together, manyfoot is used by some authors, eledmac only by one. As far as I've seen, if I don't want to just glue pdfs together, I will have to load both the packages. And indeed I will have to compare carefully the individual contributions and the combined version.

Comment: Good luck!  Sounds tricky....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping the loading order solves the problem in the MWE (and also in the actual document, according to [`a comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261853/package-conflict-eledmac-manyfoot#comment627930_261853)):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[noreledmac]{eledmac}
\usepackage[ruled,para*]{manyfoot}
\newfootnote[para]{A}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```